# Camel FTP Route calling another Route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I have an FTP route which processes an inbound text file and call's a company API to load
that data into an internal Company table. All works perfect.

I now have a case where when the FTP route is invoked, I first need to remove all the
existing data from the Company table... there is a company API to handle that case.

The problem I have is that the Company API which removes data from the Company table
also returns some information relative to the delete operation.

In this special case, I would normally want to first delete all records in the Company table
( using this Company API call ) and THEN process the inbound FTP data file.

The issue is that if I begin the ftp processing ( Step 1 ) and then call the company API ( Step 2 ) to
first delete the exiting data in the table, the inbound data from the file associated with the FTP
operation is lost prior to executing Step 3 ...what is in the context appears to be the data returned from Step 2.

Ideally, I would like the route to start ( Step 1 ) and be able to call Step 2 without destroying the
data inbound from the FTP file ...is there a way to accomplish this ? I know how to call one route
from another, just not how to prevent the FTP data from being lost when I do make the call to the other route.

```
<route id="import-data-from-ftp">
  
  <from uri="ftp: .............................">              Step 1
  
     <to uri="api:deleteData ............................." >  Step 2
     
     <to uri="api:loadData ............................." >    Step 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna comment this because I don't have the 50 reputation for comment, but is better use properties, this is because the headers can be lost every time you call an api and the properties will not be delete, so you can save the body inside a property for example

```
<route id="import-data-from-ftp">
  
  <from uri="ftp: .............................">              Step 1
  
    <setProperty name="preservedbody">
        <simple>${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
    </setProperty>

     <to uri="api:deleteData ............................." >  Step 2
     
    <setBody>
        <exchangeProperty>preservedbody</exchangeProperty>
    </setBody>

     <to uri="api:loadData ............................." >    Step 3
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct ...shortly after I posted the original answer, I read about this issue storing to the Headers ...thank you for pointing out that Properties are the better solution..

Comment: I would note that in my corrected solution I used <simple>${exchangeProperty.preservedbody}</simple>....I don't think it matters either way as regards retrieving the saved property.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by preserving the body of the message ( file content ) prior to making the call to the api:deleteData ...I then restored the body after the call ...perhaps not very elegant, but it work.

Example:

```
<route id="import-data-from-ftp">
  
  <from uri="ftp: .............................">              Step 1
  
    <setHeader name="preservedbody">
        <simple>${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
    </setHeader>

     <to uri="api:deleteData ............................." >  Step 2
     
    <setBody>
        <simple>${headers.preservedbody}</simple>
    </setBody>

     <to uri="api:loadData ............................." >    Step 3
```